# Notification sound

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to play a sound when I run an ajax request. But I don't know how to do it. I've try something like this. But it's not working at this time.
Any advices ?

```
var sound = new Audio()
sound.src('/app/assets/javascripts/audio/notif_sound1.mp3')
sound.play()
```

Comment: may be there is a method like `prepare`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450033/playing-sound-notifications-using-javascript