# How to trigger sound whenever a user clicks an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I play an mp3 or wav sound using the jquery click event?

i want to add click sound not any track or song

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript

Comment: Please tell me the URL of your web site so I can make sure I never go there.

Comment: Paul, that is simply an inappropriate response.

Comment: +1 Paul, the snark comments are perfectly acceptable in the comments section.

Comment: @PaulTomblin what if the element is a "Play" button?  Would that really be so horrible?

Comment: A "Play" button to play a click sound, sounds interesting

Comment: "Click here to hear a click".  Yeah, that sounds useful.

Comment: Guys maybe he simply wanna attach it to another event ... but seriously I ROFLED :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find the [jQuery Sound Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sound) of use:

> This is a simple sound player, it uses flash to play the sounds, but DOES NOT provide a flash interface for any controls, everything is controlled via jQuery
>
> ```
> $("#sound").sound({swf: url});
> $("#sound").load(url);
> $("#sound").play();
> $("#sound").pause();
> $("#sound").stop();
> $("#sound").volume(0-100);
> ```

Comment: it is under development once i complete it i will tell you

Comment: @Mohan I believe it's your container - something like `<div id="sound"></div>`.

Comment: I am using mp3 file, but not works for me i used like this $("#sound").sound({swf: 'www.example.com/example.mp3'});

Comment: @Mohan This (comments on this answer) wouldn't be the best place to provide support. Perhaps you could ask a new question here regarding your problem. Invite the readers to look at the source code with you and determine what (if anything) might have broken in later versions of jQuery. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use DHTML to play sound. You can use a flash player like [this one](http://www.flashmp3player.org/).