# play mp3 file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i play an mp3 file using jquery in website.I m using servlets or http to play a song.Also how can i calculate total time of song played.

Regards
Angelina

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript

Comment: Note: jQuery is a Java*Script* library. JavaScript is something totally different from Java. I edited the tags.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an element with your sound to the page:

```
var sound = $('<embed autoplay="true" height="0" width="0" />');
sound.attr('src', urlOfMyMp3);
$('body').append(sound);
```

Source: [Embed MP3 in website](http://www.labnol.org/internet/design/html-embed-mp3-songs-podcasts-music-in-blogs-websites/2232/)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like [jPlayer](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/).

Comment: jPlayer is junk in Firefox.  I do not recommend using it.