# how to play mp3 file by streaming using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i play an Mp3 file using jquery.At backend level i m using servlets/jsp.PLease suggest any other possible way to play mp3 file in a website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [play mp3  file using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920550/play-mp3-file-using-jquery)

Comment: You already asked the same question yesterday, and it's about JavaScript, not Java.