# How to hear the audio of a text to speech translation

Tags: html, audio, text-to-speech

I would want to hear the audio, when I click on an image (e.g. an audio image). The sound file for a sentence is obtained via google translate. I would like to do this without getting re-directed to a different page. How should I do this? I tried using the HTML5 audio tag, but didn't succeed either.

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=My+name+is+John">My name is John</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user339108 - see my edit. Let me know if this will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT2**

Here's [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript) also posted on SO that may help you.

---

**EDIT**

A more robust solution. Tested in IE8 and Firefox

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="http://www.blackwellokradio.com/click-me.jpg" onclick="$.sound.play('http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=My+name+is+John')" style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;" />
  </body>
</html>     
<!--Ideally you would put this in a separate file. src: http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/plugins/sound/jquery.sound.js?rev=5750-->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
/**
 * jQuery sound plugin (no flash)
 * 
 * port of script.aculo.us' sound.js (http://script.aculo.us), based on code by Jules Gravinese (http://www.webveteran.com/) 
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2007 JÃ¶rn Zaefferer (http://bassistance.de) 
 * 
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   
 * $Id$
 */

/**
 * API Documentation
 * 
 * // play a sound from the url
 * $.sound.play(url)
 * 
 * // play a sound from the url, on a track, stopping any sound already running on that track
 * $.sound.play(url, {
 *   track: "track1"
 * });
 * 
 * // increase the timeout to four seconds before removing the sound object from the dom for longer sounds
 * $.sound.play(url, {
 *   timeout: 4000
 * });
 * 
 * // stop a sound by removing the element returned by play
 * var sound = $.sound.play(url);
 * sound.remove();
 * 
 * // disable playing sounds
 * $.sound.enabled = false;
 * 
 * // enable playing sounds
 * $.sound.enabled = true
 */

(function($) {

$.sound = {
    tracks: {},
    enabled: true,
    template: function(src) {
        return '<embed style="height:0" loop="false" src="' + src + '" autostart="true" hidden="true"/>';
    },
    play: function(url, options){
        if (!this.enabled)
            return;
        var settings = $.extend({
            url: url,
            timeout: 2000
        }, options);

        if (settings.track) {
            if (this.tracks[settings.track]) {
                var current = this.tracks[settings.track];
                // TODO check when Stop is avaiable, certainly not on a jQuery object
                current.Stop && current.Stop();
                current.remove();  
            }
        }

        var element = $.browser.msie
            ? $('<bgsound/>').attr({
                src: settings.url,
                loop: 1,
                autostart: true
              })
            : $(this.template(settings.url));

        element.appendTo("body");

        if (settings.track) {
            this.tracks[settings.track] = element;
        }

        if(options){
            setTimeout(function() {
                element.remove();
            }, options.timeout)
        }

        return element;
    }
};

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

---

Here's a way embedding Quicktime. You can just as easily use Windows Media Player...

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" width="300" height="50">
        <param name="src" value="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=My+name+is+John">
        <param name="autoplay" value="true">
        <embed type="audio/x-wav" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=My+name+is+John" autoplay="true" autostart="true" width="300" height="50">
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This still doesn't do what I want to achieve. I would ideally want to associate this translation to an audio image, so whenever the end user clicks on this image the sound needs to be translated based on the above URL. I don't want it to re-direct or show the audio controls. How do I achieve that

Comment: Brandon's solution seems correct. To achieve your intended effect, set autostart: false, hide the div that you load the embed/object tag into, and associate the image.onclick with the play function