# How to execute a href without redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-to-speech

I want to execute a href without redirecting me to the page. execution in background.
here is my code

```
    <a id="speechOutputLink" href="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q=text" rel="noreferrer" >Download</a>
```

When i click on the the href Download i don't want to be redirected to the page of google translator. How can i do this?

Comment: What exactly do you want if you don't want to be redirected?  Do you need to do some javascript process instead of going to the url or you want it to open in another tab or window?

Comment: The href i'm executing redirect me to the google translator audio playin the text in the href. What i want is to get the audio charged without redirecting me to the google translator page

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery's `event.preventDefault()` method](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

> *If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.*

```
$('a#speechOutputLink').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the 'target' tag to your anchor allows you to open the page in the background or in an iframe, etc. The values accepted are

```
_blank
_parent
_self
_top
framename
<a id="speechOutputLink" href="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q=text" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Additionally you could use the jquery method event.preventDefault() although i've found this to not always work as expected depending on other javascript tasks running.

Comment: Even with target="_blanc" i am always redirected to the google translator page

Comment: Im not following what you're trying to do here.  Do you want that sound clip to just play on your page?

Comment: exactlly. I want the audio to be played on my own page

Comment: AH.  Then the real issue is that this is a google TTS (text to speech) audio file.  Using an <a> tag won't be the way to go.  There are a few examples and dup questions i found.  Check out  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853254/how-to-hear-the-audio-of-a-text-to-speech-translation)

Comment: [This Article](http://www.konradkiss.com/2012/01/embedding-text-to-speech-into-html5_18.html) may be more updated with an HTML5 way to to do this as well.

Comment: Also, just thinking about it...but you could have a hidden iframe, and have your <a href> target that hidden iframe.  Theoretically (i haven't tested it) that should load the frame into the hidden iframe and play the sound when clicked.

Comment: No didn't find a solution yet