# Adding sound to JQuery Cycle Plugin

Tags: jquery

I am using the JQuery Plugin and would like to add sound for when my slideshow is going. I am using the shuffle effect and whenever it is to go to the next slide I would like a sound to be played.

```
$('#chars').cycle({
    fx:     'shuffle',
    prev:   '#prev',
    next:   '#next',
    timeout: 6000,
    speed:  800
});
```

jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ - That is the Plugin site.

These are the js files I am using.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was thinking vrooOOOOOOOOOoom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this previous question:

[Cross-platform, cross-browser way to play sound from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript)

And use what you learn from that to play a sound from within Cycle's [before and after callbacks](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html), e.g.:

```
$('#chars').cycle({
    fx:     'shuffle',
    prev:   '#prev',
    next:   '#next',
    timeout: 6000,
    speed:  800,
    after: function() { soundPlay("vrooOOoom"); }
});
```

Comment: This seems like it will be a great solution. I am still having a couple issues. I cannot install a plugin on firefox so I am going to work on that. In IE the sound works the first time and then does not work again. 

I made a simple function that just shows an alert box and it works perfectly.

Comment: Edit your question to show your new code that partially works