# Javascript sounds in Android and Iphone browser

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, audio

I'm developing simple javascript game,
which should be embeded in Android and Iphone in-app browser.
I have problem with sounds. I tried this, works good on PC,
but not working on android and works strange with big delays on iphone.

init:

```
var hitSound = new Audio('hit.wav');
```

play:

```
hitSound.play();
```

How to play sounds without delay on Android and Iphone  browser?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to use a HTML5 feature, which is not fully supported by Android's browser, at least up to FroYo. Still, if you use Android's `WebView` you can do the trick, but probably you are avoiding Native apps, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.scriptwell.net/howtoplaysound.htm) would help.

look for the page section where this is discussed:

> The above two functions should be
>   placed in the HEAD section between a
>
> ```
>       <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> and a
> ```
>
> .
>
> The best place and time to invoke the
>   setEmbed function is in the BODY tag
>   after page load:
>
> ```
>       <body onload=   "setEmbed('sample',
> ```
>
> 'http://www.yourdomain.com/music/')">

Comment: can you be please more specific?

Comment: @Janci I said look into the page where these quoted lines are written.

Comment: tryied everything, nothing is good enough, also found similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript,  but it's not working on iphone...