# jQuery or Java sound notification / alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have a link `<a href="#" id="button">click</a>` on my page and I want to play a notification or alert beep on click. How can I do this using jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-platform, cross-browser way to play sound from Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript)

Comment: no.. the question is different... I already made a walk..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the **[jQuery sound](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sound_plugin)** plugin.

Comment: Just in case someone actually believes this can't be done in plain javascript, here's the code in that plugin: `$("body").append('<embed id="' + id + '" src="'+url+'" autostart="true" hidden="true"></embed>');`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery..

```
<BGSOUND ID="SOUND_ID" LOOP=1 VOLUME="-200" SRC="mySound.mid">

document.all['SOUND_ID'].src='mySound.mid';
```

If you need a more fancy player you will need to embed on of those Flash player and pass your mp3 file as source. Search for it, there are many.

Comment: 10 years ago it would have been a great tip :). AFAIK it is supported only in IE, but in IE8 they might have stopped supporting it.

Comment: I agree. But the jQuery sound plugin in Caspar's answer builds around pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5's `audio` element.

[HTML5 audio on Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-the-html-5-audio-element/) - there is a jQuery example