# Playing Sound Javascript or HTML

Tags: javascript, html, audio, playback

I need to Implement an object(or sth else) to play sounds in Web.

I've searched a lot but there were nothing that can play sounds in each browser. I mean that there was a code for each browser.

My question is that if there is a code that can be used in every browser.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad English!!!!!!

Comment: A similar question answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May we can start by throwing some light on 5 widely accepted ways to add sound on ur webpage.

1. **MIDI Files** - Small Size, Easy to implements but looks amateurish n dicy.
2. **WAV Files** - Easy again, but they don't loop. So file size may get bigger too.
3. **MP3 Files** - Ensure quality, but required external player, certainly not user-friendly.
4. **Flash Files** - Flexible, Small and can loop. The only road block, creating one of ur own requires buying a Flash software.
5. **Pre-build Flash Loops** - Small, made by professionals (www.flashmusictracks.com, www.flashkit.com). See if u can find something to suit u. Thr cud be more sites like i mentioned.

Just so u know, Google used flash loops when it embedded sounds for its [pacman logo](http://www.google.com/pacman/), on its home page.

Answer (score 1):

For HTML5 you can use audio tag

```
<audio src="hello.wav"></audio>
```