# best way to add sounds to navigation buttons?

Tags: javascript, css, audio

I have a client who has a young target audience and needs his site to play short "catch phrases" when the user clicks buttons. What would be the best way to go about this? I don't necessarily want to use Flash.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a quick dropdown solution, try [this library](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/).  (I've played a bit with it, and it seems reasonable.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it. If someone is using old, crappy browser then he just won't hear a clip - that's not a very big problem I guess.

You could do that using hidden `<audio>` element and [piece of JavaScript](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introduction-to-the-html5-audio-tag-javascript-manipulation/).

Comment: You don't even have to hide it, just omit the controls boolean and you won't see it anyway.

Comment: So essentially, each navigation item will be a play button?

Comment: Just add a `click` listener to every button which fires a function that basically do nothing more but `document.getElementById("sound-player").play();`.