# php: play sound when receiving a message

Tags: php, message, ring

Ex: i have mp3 file <- that is for message sound

i want to make a restaurant's script, when the customer make an order, the sound is rings in the employee's browser.

Can I make something like this in the php or jquery or ajax?

please help me

Thank you

Comment: Open this link and hope you can find a better solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483455/play-sound-when-message-received/15498712#15498712

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use php to record the customer data to record the customer's order data. But to play a message you will have to use javascript. Here's a link that might help

[Cross-platform, cross-browser way to play sound from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript)

Comment: this example to play sound in the same user, i want the sound ring in the admin user

Answer (score 0):

What kind of browser support are looking at?  This is achievable with the HTML5 audio JS api. If you are looking for wider browser support, you will probably want to use Flash to hold the sounds.

Comment: ex: when you order from pizzahut online, i think there is a sound play when you finish the order.