# How do I detect if quicktime is installed with javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows, browser, quicktime

I want to play a sound notification, so I used the method described here: [Cross-platform, cross-browser way to play sound from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript) However, when quicktime is not installed on the client machine, everytime the `soundPlay` function is called, a windows popup shows up. It says that quicktime is not installed, and proposes to install it.

For user experience, I would like not to bother users without quicktime like this:

```
function hasQuickTime() {
  // how do I know ?
}

// play sound only if quickTime is installed
if (hasQuickTime()) {
  soundPlay();
}
```

Comment: Here is basically the same script: http://dithered.chadlindstrom.ca/javascript/quicktime.html But you might prefer the more specific examples and the detailed way things are explained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Apple's JavaScript Scripting Guide: [Detecting QuickTime with JavaScript](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/bQTScripting_JavaScri_Document/QuickTimeandJavaScri.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001526-CH001-SW1)

```
var haveqt = false;

if (navigator.plugins) {
    for (i=0; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++ ) {
        if (navigator.plugins[i].name.indexOf
        ("QuickTime") >= 0)
        { haveqt = true; }
    }
}

if ((navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") > 0)
    && (navigator.appName.substring(0,9) == "Microsoft")
    && (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) < 5) )
{ haveqt = true; }
```

You can test the variable `haveqt` for the presence of QuickTime.