# Background sound on action

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a facebook like chat, and we want to be able to play a sound when someone receives a new message. What is the best way to go about this? If needed it is ok if we use HTML5 for this, but preferrably a cross-browser solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-platform, cross-browser way to play sound from Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript)

Comment: there are a ton of already asked questions pertaining to this subject, look at the **Related** column on the right hand of the screen.

Comment: Eish, when typing the question I didn't see any matching questions, but I do now on the right-hand side. tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy with HTML5

```
 <audio id="mySoundClip">
    <source src="audio/beep.mp3"></source>
    <source src="audio/beep.ogg"></source>
    Your browser isn't invited for super fun audio time.
 </audio>
```

and the jQuery bit

```
var audio = $("#mySoundClip")[0];
audio.play();
```

This will provide support for Firefox 3.5+, Chrome 3+, Opera 10.5+, Safari 4+, & IE 9+

Answer (score 0):

For a cross browser solution, you might want to look at [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/). You can create an `<audio>` element on your page, hide it, and call `.play` on it whenever you want the sound to play.