# Start and stop for a embeded music in html using javascript works only in IE

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I have embeded a music in a webpage using this code:

```
<embed src="upload/gnossiennes.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" hidden="true"></embed>
```

Then I am using this javascript code to start/stop it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function play() {
        document.embeds[0].play();
    }
    function stop() {
        document.embeds[0].stop();
    }
</script> 

<span><a href="#" onClick="play();">START</a></span>
<span><a href="#" onClick="stop();">STOP</a></span>
```

This works only in IE but not in Chrome, FireFox and Opera. What can be the problem? (this is the only embed in the page so I guess `document.embeds[0]` is only referring to this embed and shouldnt be the problem, unless this array does not exist in other browsers!

Comment: and you have to use `embed` and can't use `audio`? or would be a solution with `audio` also okay?

Comment: Well I would use anything that works...I am thinking of cross borwser compatibiity and being able to start / stop the music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well referencing one `<embed>` could be fatal for prospective uses of more embed tags. If you simply want to `start` and `stop`it then simply create and remove it as a DOM element. Here was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript) and had the same solution

Comment: That question is four years old.